# Equation in debug mode with different value than if not

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

So I am writing an excel VBA program that reads all csv files with a specific name into separate sheets on the workbook.

It is reading the files with no issue. The problem comes when it is translating the data from the file onto an array which is meant to contain all the relevant data in all the files of the directory.

To read the files and separating by line,

I am using:

```
Do Until EOF(1)

        Line Input #1, LineFromFile

        lineitems = Split(LineFromFile, Chr(10))
```

Further down the module, I am passing the lineitems to a data array when a specific criteria within that line of data is met. For clarity, the expression is comparing the date value in the line of the file with the date marker on the name of the file.

```
ElseIf (Left(lineitems(Line), 8) = Right(Left(FileTime(FileNum), 6), 2) + "/" + Right(Left(FileTime(FileNum), 4), 2) + "/" + Left(FileTime(FileNum), 2)) Then                 

                Proxy = CStr(lineitems(Line))
                DataArray(InverterNumber - 1, m(InverterNumber - 1)) = Proxy
```

As you can see, I've added a proxy step to try and ensure the data goes across, to no avail. I've also added a fail-safe to ensure no empty line goes into DataArray:

```
If Len(DataArray(InverterNumber - 1, m(InverterNumber - 1))) = Len(CStr(lineitems(Line))) Then

                    Test(InverterNumber - 1, m(InverterNumber - 1)) = Len(DataArray(InverterNumber - 1, m(InverterNumber - 1)))
                    m(InverterNumber - 1) = m(InverterNumber - 1) + 1

                End If
```

Now if I run the program in it's release modus, it will return a series of empty columns, which shouldn't happen because of the failsafe.
However when I run it through the debug mode, and IF I observe that step, it adds the data correctly.

Is there any way I can ensure the values are being translated correctly?

Is there anything I could be doing better?

Comment: Can you provide the full module, as your question would lead to a lot of assumption on the part of anyone who would want to answer it ? Add some example strings that would be analysed by your code. As you insert a number of arrays into other arrays (DataArray(InverterNumber - 1, m(InverterNumber - 1)) where we can't see how they are built ?

Comment: You can download the compiler and the files from this dropbox folder:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9sph17eyc2m0gq3/AACunecHXcqpMBAiP5CUEvUJa?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

This reads a single line from your file, but does not return the newline character(s) which delimit the line:

```
Line Input #1, LineFromFile
```

Then this:

```
lineitems = Split(LineFromFile, Chr(10))
```

Do you really have line feed characters within the "lines" of your CSV file?  If yes then it would help to show some sample content.

Comment: I've added in a DropBox folder with the files:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9sph17eyc2m0gq3/AACunecHXcqpMBAiP5CUEvUJa?dl=0

Not sure what you mean by line feed characters, though...